# How do I tell the difference between an acid, base, and a salt solution?

Tags: acid-base

I'm learning about acid-base equilibria. I know that a (Bronsted-Lowry) acid donates a hydrogen proton, and a base receives a hydrogen proton, but I've also heard about a Lewis acid base theory, where electrons are the key difference. What's the point of making it even more general?And I'm not sure exactly what an salt is. I know it contains a cation and anion, but don't acids and bases have that as well?

---

Further edit has made a chameleon transition to ( rollback applied ):

**What characteristics make a salt acidic or basic?**

Let's use the example $\ce{NaC_2H_3O_2}$ (sodium acetate).

It disassociates into $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{C_2H_3O_2-}$. Why is the sodium ion not react with water, but the acetate ion does?
How can you tell if a anion and cation of a salt will react in water (if placed in water)?

Comment: KHPO4 is all of them. An acid, a base and a salt.

Comment: H2O is an acid and a base, too.

Comment: @Poutnik so it's dependent on what it's reacting with? for ones that have more than one characteristics?

Comment: Sorry, should be KH2PO4 ( or K2HPO4 or KHSO4). The above applies to all of them.

Comment: What you just did is called a "chameleon question". After it was answered, it was edited to become very different, or follow up question, more or less destroying the original content and relation to the answers . This can be considered rude to those who put effort into answering and should be avoided. The better, recommended and expected way is to post a new question, referring eventually to the original one as the follow up question, if it applies .

Comment: @Poutnik sorry I didn't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather, all depends on what aspects or criteria you evaluate.

- If the compound fits criteria for [salts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(chemistry)), it is a salt.
- If the compound fits criteria for [acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid), it is an acid.
- If the compound fits criteria for [bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(chemistry)), it is a base.

And the main point is - these categories are not mutually exclusive.

Additionally, there are 2 meanings for an acid/base.

1. Fitting criteria of [Broensted-Lawry theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%B8nsted%E2%80%93Lowry_acid%E2%80%93base_theory), resp. [Lewis theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases).
2. A practical meaning: ability of forming ( strongly ) acidic or alkaline solutions.

   - Is it acidic ? It is an acid.
   - Is it alkaline ? It is a base.
   - Is it about neutral and conducting electricity well ? It is a salt.

A compound can be acid(1),base(1) or salt, while being base(2), as it is a stronger base(1) than an acid(1). And vice versa.

---

Addressing feedback:

E.g. classical soap is a salt AND a base. So is e.g. sodium  carbonate.

Like quantum objects manifest wave-like or particle-like properties, depending on scenario,  compounds manifest scenario dependent salt-like or base/acid-like properties.

Solid $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is more like a salt,  being ionic compound, while its solution is more like a base solution, with carbonate anion capturing hydronium ions and causing alkaline $\mathrm{pH}$.

$\ce{NaOH}$ as the typical strong base can be in its solid form formally considered as a sodium salt of the very weak acid $\ce{H2O}$ , what makes its anion $\ce{OH-}$ , when $\ce{NaOH}$ is dissolved, a very strong Broensted-Lawry conjugate base.

Comment: In the bases entry, why does Wikipedia show a picture of a soap stating that "Soaps are weak bases formed by the reaction of fatty acids with sodium hydroxide or potassium hydroxide." Soaps are weakly alkaline but they are salts not bases. What do you think?

Comment: See the A update.

Comment: @Wise sequoia well a salt is when an acid and a base react .For example when sodium (the base) and sulfuric acid (the acid) react it forms sodium sulfate(the salt) and hydrogen gas.